Issues with Dependencies in Firebase App Hosting and Cloud Functions Deployments for Next.js App
I am working on a Next.js project deployed using Firebase App Hosting (not Firebase Hosting), and I recently added Cloud Functions to my setup. I uncommented the example function:
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";

export const helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

The deployment of Cloud Functions works fine when I run:
firebase deploy --only functions
However, when I deploy the full application with App Hosting, I encounter an error indicating that some dependencies cannot be found. I suspect the issue has to do with how App Hosting handles the dependencies for both my app and the Cloud Functions.
Cloud build error logs
Here is a brief overview of my setup:

App Hosting (for Next.js) is being used to deploy the web app.
Firebase Functions are deployed via firebase-functions using TypeScript.
Both my app and functions have separate package.json files, and I ensure that the functions are deployed using their own dependencies within the functions/ directory.

/project_name
├── /app
├── /components
├── /functions
│   ├── /lib
│   ├── /src
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── .eslintrc.js
├── /public
├── .firebaserc
├── firebase.json
├── apphosting.yaml
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── next.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── next.config.mjs


./functions/package.json:
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

./functions/tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}

./functions/.eslintrc.js:
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
    "/generated/**/*", // Ignore generated files.
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "indent": ["error", 2],
  },
};


./firebase.json:
{
  "emulators": {
    "auth": { "port": 9099 },
    "functions": { "port": 5001 },
    "firestore": { "port": 8080 },
    "storage": { "port": 9199 },
    "ui": { "enabled": true },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "firebasestorage.rules"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log",
        "*.local"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


./tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

./package.json:
{
  "name": "project_name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-image-compression": "^2.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "firebase": "^10.13.1",
    "next": "14.2.11",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.11",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

The Issue:
The full app deployment (using App Hosting) fails with errors related to missing dependencies. However, deploying just the Cloud Functions works fine. I suspect there’s a conflict in how the app's dependencies and functions' dependencies are managed when App Hosting builds the project.

Ensured that the functions directory has its own package.json with the necessary dependencies listed.
Checked to ensure the app’s package.json only contains dependencies relevant to the Next.js build.
Verified that environment variables in the apphosting.yaml are correctly configured.

I expected that since deploying functions independently works, that it would also work when deploying via app hosting.
What I Need Help With:

Are there any known issues with Firebase App Hosting when deploying a Next.js app alongside Cloud Functions?
Are there any Firebase-specific steps I should follow to ensure the App Hosting environment correctly handles dependencies for both my app and the Cloud Functions?


I was able to solve this by excluding the functions folder in ./tsconfig.json and deploying functions separately with firebase deploy --only functions:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./functions"]
}

